# Overwrite styles of a component inside another in react

Tags: reactjs, react-css-modules

I have a component with its own styles:

import styles from './componentA.module.scss';

**componentA.module.scss:**

```
.A { color: green;
     background: white;
     font-size: 1rem;}
```

**ComponentA.js**

```
....
return(
   <div className={styles.A}>{props.children}</div>
)
```

I have a ComponentB.js.  In this component B I need the component A, but I need to overwrite the style color.

**ComponentB.js**

```
...
import ComponentA from './../componentA';
import styles from 'componentB.module.scss';
...
return(
<ComponentA />
)
```

but I want in the component B overwrite the color to the class .A.  I tried in componentB.module.scss to do it and it doesn't change.

**componentB.module.scss**

```
.A {
 color: red !important;
}
```

and it doesn't work I want to be able to overwrite the styles depending on the component that is wrapped.  How can I do it?  Thanks.

Comment: Have ComponentA take in `className` as a prop and pass it through, e.g. `className={\`${styles.A} ${className}\``, then just apply your styling to it via B's styling: `<ComponentA className={styles.overrideA}` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass Component A styles by the props and then apply to the wrapper div

```
const ComponentA = (props) => {

  return(
    <div className={styles.A} styles={props.cssStyles}>{props.children}</div>
    )
  }
```

And then

```
import ComponentA from './../componentA';
import styles from 'componentB.module.scss';
...
return(
<ComponentA cssStyles={{color: "red"}} />
)
```

You can also pass classnames as props and then merge default classnames and props classnames by this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames